# How do I recognize GRANTED and UNACCEPTED of permissions?

Tags: java, android, permissions, runtime-permissions

**I use this code to recognize permissions in onCreate:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
     requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 100);
```

**And in activity I use this code snippet to check, allow or deny the permissions :**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode) {
     case 100: {
         if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         else
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  }
}
```

and in Manifest.xml :

```
<!-- *****  Uses Permission  ***** -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But it always returns the value of zero in the code, both when it is verified and when it is rejected.

### How do I tell if the user has verified or denied?

Comment: Did you tried in other android mobile?

Comment: Yes, both in Samsung Note-5 (Android 7.0) and Samsung j7-prime (Android 6.0.1)

Comment: Try Dexter library its easy to use and quite simple.
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: I do not want to use the library and I need to learn how to use it from Android (Pure Android) , However, I also used this library, but my problem did not resolve , Please tell without a library how to get exactly **the status of permissions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried ur example and it gives proper result with 0 and -1.
**0 for Granted** and 
**-1 for Denied**.

that might be device problem and don't use emulator for this, otherwise your code works just fine.
here is my snapshot:

```
01-13 13:00:29.134 30051-30051/com.usense.netsense I/get_permission:  permissions[0]= android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE grantResults[0]= 0
01-13 13:00:29.134 30051-30051/com.usense.netsense I/get_permission:  permissions[1]= android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE grantResults[1]= -1
01-13 13:00:29.134 30051-30051/com.usense.netsense I/get_permission:  permissions[2]= android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE grantResults[2]= -1
```

Comment: But for me it comes to zero in all states!

Comment: plz try with other devices except samsung because samsung devices are problematic sometimes. Otherwise problem is something else since, your code is correct.